# How do I privately implement an operator for an STL container?

Tags: c++, scope, stl, operator-overloading, unordered-map

Say we have something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class SparseMatrix {
    // Where the first (K,V) is (row_idx, columns) and the second is (col_idx, numeric type)  
    using Entries = std::unordered_map<unsigned long, std::unordered_map<unsigned long, T>>;
    Entries data;
    //...
};
```

For sparse matrices, we want to ignore rows that are mutually empty, so (I think) we could implement addition with something like this:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
std::unordered_map<K, V> operator+(
    const std::unordered_map<K,V>& left, 
    const std::unordered_map<K,V>& right
) {
    std::unordered_map<K, V> result(left); 
    for (auto& p: result) {
        if (right.count(p.first) > 0) {
            result[p.first] += right[p.first]; // += def'n not shown...
        }
    }

    for (auto& p: right) {
        if (result.count(p.first) == 0) { 
            result[p.first] = p.second;
        }
    }

    return result;
} 

// ...

SparseMatrix::SparseMatrix operator+(const SparseMatrix& right)
{
    // checks and whatnot...
    // Uses the custom + operator: the "sum" of two unordered_maps!!!
    return this->data + right.data;
}
```

I think this template is convenient because it handles the outer and inner operations simultaneously; however, because this should happen in a header file, if possible I'd like to make the `unordered_map` operator definition private to  `SparseMatrix`, as it only has meaning there. I do not want  `std::unordered_map<K,V> operator+` to be visibly defined for anyone who #includes this implementation.

What idiomatic options do I have, other than globally declaring the operator definition(s) for the STL container?

If anything else I've drafted above is not idiomatic C++, I'd really appreciate any feedback.

Naively, I tried to paste that implementation in SparseMatrix 's private section, and ran into an error which states I'm providing too many parameters to the function. Removing the `left` parameter and replacing it with the private member, data, then results in the + operation not being defined for MatrixVals . My assumption for what's going on here is possibly that I've introduced a circular dependency. Is that the case?

I did not find any other SO post describing how to limit the scope of an operator overload in this way.

Comment: You should have a free function accepting two SparceMatrix instances not a free function adding two unordered maps (and this free function should be a friend of your SparceMatrix class to access the private unordered maps)

Comment: It is often a bad idea to add operators for classes you don't own. Prefer instead to simply give the function any other non-operator name.

Comment: Apparently you cant make a `operator+(unordered_map, unordered_map)` `static`. I can declare it a `friend`, but it doesn't seem to be found during Argument Dependent Lookup. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2462efb668d95b47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Operators for classes you don't own is generally a bad idea**

But we can still do it. Making it `static` or `friend` inside the class scope doesn't seem to work, so the best way seems to be to put it into a private namespace.

```
namespace SparseMatrixImpl {
    
    template<typename K, typename V>
    std::unordered_map<K, V> operator+(
        std::unordered_map<K,V>& left, 
        std::unordered_map<K,V>& right
    ) {
       ...
    } 
}
```

and then pull that function into the overload set when you need it

```
SparseMatrix::SparseMatrix operator+(const SparseMatrix& right)
{
    // checks and whatnot...
    // Uses the custom + operator: the "sum" of two unordered_maps!!!
    using SparseMatrixImpl::operator+;
    return this->data + right.data;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f65464c73b727e0

**The better idea**

is to simply call it something else, that *is* globally useful, such as `accumulate`.

```
    template<typename K, typename V>
    std::unordered_map<K, V> accumulate(
        std::unordered_map<K,V>& left, 
        std::unordered_map<K,V>& right
    ) {
       ...
    }
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b22e87354ccedf

---

Also you have a variety of other errors and bad ideas in the code. Namely, that you're trying to use `operator[]` on a `const` `right`.

Comment: Thank you for this response. Taking a step back, you're right that the best approach is to not use an operator for something I don't own. Thanks for going a step further and even taking a stab at implementing my bad idea. Currently, this resolves what I was trying to work through.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6eMhE3YbE

Jettisoned the += and threw in a compile time conditional to terminate the recursion if the last value types were non-unordered maps, per some other examples I found on SO.

Thanks for your feedback. Hopefully that last example isn't as gross and I'm converging on something that is more or less conventional...

@Mooing Duck

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24c61d838bbb8962 is probably what I'd do. Generic map `accumulate` methods (mirroring [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)), where the operator can handle arbitrary nesting. Note the use of `find` which means I only do the hash lookup once. Your code does the hash lookup 2-3 times per key.